# ListView items not clickable with HorizontalScrollView inside

Tags: android, listview

I have quite a complicated `ListView`. Each item looks something like this:

```
> LinearLayout (vertical)
  > LinearLayout (horizontal)
    > include (horizontal LinearLayout with two TextViews)
    > include (ditto)
    > include (ditto)
  > TextView
  > HorizontalScrollView (this guy is my problem)
    > LinearLayout (horizontal)
```

In my activity, when an item is created (`getView()` is called) I add dynamic `TextView`s to the `LinearLayout` inside the `HorizontalScrollView` (besides filling the other, simpler stuff out). Amazingly, performance is pretty good.

My problem is that when I added the `HorizontalScrollView`, my list items became unclickable. They don't get the orange background when clicked and they don't fire the `OnItemClickedListener` I have set up (to do a simple `Log.d` call).

How can I make my list items clickable again?

---

**Edit:** setting `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the topmost `LinearLayout` seems to work. I'd like to know if there are other ways, though: what if I want focusable items in my list items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the topmost `LinearLayout` did the trick. Elements inside can still be made "clickable", they're just not focusable (i.e. you can't click them on a non-touchscreen device). Good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

when i applied HorizontalScrollView to my TableLayout scrolling is working fine but unable to click on list item 
My layout is as follwos

> Linearlayout
>   HorizontalScrollView
>    TableLayout
>    .........
>   /TableLayout
>   /HorizontalScrollView
>   /LinearLayout

i applied android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to my top most linearlayout Any Help

Answer (score 0):

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

didn't help for me.
So

So, i realized listener patern.

```
public interface EventListItemOnClickListener {
    public void itemClicked();
}
```

And in adapter notify all listeners

```
private List<EventListItemOnClickListener> listeners;
protected void notifyOnClick(int position){
  for(int i=0; i<listeners.size();++i)
    listeners.get(i).itemClicked((Event)events.get(position));
}
...
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      notifyOnClick(position);
    }
...
```